# How to redirect/forward request in php?

Tags: php, http, httprequest, httpful

I use httpful to send http request and get the response to display in request.php

```
include('httpful.phar');

$response = \Httpful\Request::get('http://domain/response.php')->send();

echo '<textarea rows="20" cols="100">';
echo $response;
echo '</textarea>';
```

In response.php, I use header to redirect the request to another page, but I cannot get the expected response.

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location:http://otherdomain/other_response.php");

echo 'internal response page'
```

I have also tried

```
header("HTTP/1.1 302 Found");
```

but it still only get the response 'internal response page'

what is the correct way to redirect/forward the request to other_response.php?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, you may only use header(); once. And it has to output before anything else. From the code that you showed, I don't see any mistakes besides that.

Comment: You can have multiple header calls to  send different headers. You are right about sending headers before anything else though.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the code for the package, I found a `followRedirects` method ([here](https://github.com/nategood/httpful/blob/0cded3ea97ba905600de9ceb9ef13f3ab681587c/src/Httpful/Request.php#L201)). It looks like you have to call this method and pass it `true`. In your case, it would look like this:

```
include('httpful.phar');

$response = \Httpful\Request::get('http://domain/response.php')
    ->followRedirects(true)
    ->send();

echo '<textarea rows="20" cols="100">';
echo $response;
echo '</textarea>';
```

The `followRedirects(true)` call instructs the request to follow the redirects you have in your response.php. Also note, usually when you want to send a redirect header, you put a `exit()` call right after the header so you don't execute anything else.